# debugserver on jailbroken device

Tags: ios, debugging, jailbreak

I try to run a patched (add entitlements) version of debugserver but I got an error - `Killed - 9`
I executed the dmesg binary and I found out that it's probably because AMFI

> /usr/bin/debugserver: Possible race detected. Rejecting. AMFI: code
>   signature validation failed.

According to what I read, I can pass the bootloader a parameter that I will boot the kernel with AMFI disabled (amfi_get_out_of_my_way).

Is there any way to do it without any hardware accessories? 
PS: I am using LiberiOS jailbreak

Answer (score 3):

May be a little late but a simple solution I found to get over all codesigning errors was to deploy an app through XCode and then look under /Developer/usr/bin for debugserver, it should be there. Once in there, just copy it from there into /usr/bin